# Using a function with parameters in a template literal

Tags: javascript

I am dynamically inserting html in to the DOM when a form is submitted. When this content is created, I would like to add a delete function when the corresponding button is created. The issue I am facing is that I am unsure how I can use a function in a template literal that has a parameter. My function keeps running when the page loads!

```
const deletePost = (id) => {
    console.log("Delete Button Was clicked ");
  }

function renderPost(title, date, body, author, id) {
// renderPost()
postHolder.innerHTML += `<div class="post">
                              <div class="deleteButton"><button onclick=${deletePost(id)}><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button></div>
                              <div class="headerPosted">
                                  <div class="titlePosted">
                                      ${title}
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="datePosted">
                                      ${date}
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="bodyPosted">
                                  ${body}
                              </div>
                              <div class="authorPosted">
                                  -"${author}"
                              </div>
                          </div>`;


 }
```

Here is a codepen to test: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/klaurtar/pen/KKpLJWj)

Answer (score 2):

Simply wrap the dynamic variable with `${...}`

Try

```
<button onclick=deletePost(${id})>
```

**Demo:**

```html
<script>
  const deletePost = (id) => {
    console.log("Delete Button Was clicked ");
  }

  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {  
    function renderPost(title, date, body, author, id) {
    // renderPost()
    var postHolder = document.getElementById('postHolder');
    postHolder.innerHTML += `<div class="post">
                                <div class="deleteButton"><button onclick=deletePost(${id})><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button></div>
                                <div class="headerPosted">
                                    <div class="titlePosted">
                                        ${title}
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="datePosted">
                                        ${date}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="bodyPosted">
                                    ${body}
                                </div>
                                <div class="authorPosted">
                                    -"${author}"
                                </div>
                            </div>`;


    }
    renderPost('test',new Date(),'some body','test author',123);
 });
</script>

<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="postHolder"></div>
```

Comment: I receive the error Uncaught ReferenceError: deletePost is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Comment: @klaurtar1, please check the demo code where the function *deletePost* is declared outside of  `DOMContentLoaded` event:)